# Where and how do I write code for login and register the user using mongoose so that I can save it to the database

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, passport-local

I am doing a hands on to understand the passport strategy of `passport-local` So I have degined this much of code.I need to know what all logic should I code here.
I am using `Angular2` `ionic2` `node.js` `express.js` and `mongoose`.

`passport.js`

```
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var User = require('./user');


passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));
```

The above file contaions the code to implement passport strategy i.e `passport-local`.

`user.js`

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = moongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String,
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('User',UserSchema);
```

The above is my user schema which contains my user model.

`routes.js`

```
var passport = require('passport');
var Service = require('./app/passport');
var authController  = require('./app/controllers/authentication');//this file is empty.

var requireLogin = passport.authenticate('local',{session:false});

module.exports = function(app){

    var auth = express.Router();

    app.use('/api/auth', auth);

    auth.post('/register',function(req, res){
        authController.register(req,res);
    } );

    auth.post('/login', requireLogin, function(req, res){
        authController.login(req, res);
    });
};
```

The above contains the routes.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use below code on passport

   ```
   passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
       usernameField: 'userId'
     },
   function(username, password, done) {
       User.findOne({ email: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
         // Return if user not found in database
         if (!user) {
           return done(null, false, {
     message: 'User not found.. check username'
     });
         }
       // Return if password is wrong
       if (!user.validPassword(password)) {
        return done(null, false, {
       message: 'Password is wrong'
      });
     }
      // If credentials are correct, return the user object
     return done(null, user);
    });
    }
    ));
   ```
2. To register use below logic/code

   ```
   var register = function(req, res){
   var data = req.body;

   if(!data.emailId || !data.password){
   res.json({
       "error": true,
       "errmsg": 'missing fieid value',
       "user": {}        
   });    
   } else {
   var newUser = new User({
   Email: data.emailId,
   Password: data.password
   });

   // save the user
   newUser.save(function(err, user) {
   console.log(err);
   if (err){
     res.json({
           "error": true,
           "errmsg": err,
           "user": {}
       });
   } else {
     res.json({
           "error": false,
           "errmsg": null,
           "user": user
     });            
   }             
   });
   }   
   }
   ```
3. To login

   ```
   var login = function(req, res){
   passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
   var token;

    // If Passport throws/catches an error
   if (err) {
   res.json({
           "error": true,
           "errmsg": err,
           "user": {}        
   });
    return;
   }

    // If a user is found
   if(user){
   //console.log('token',user);
   token = user.generateJwt();
   res.status(200);
   res.json({
         "error": false,
         "errmsg": null,
         "user": token
     });
    } else {
    // If user is not found
    res.status(200).json({
           "error": true,
           "errmsg": info.message,
           "user": {}        
    });
    }
    })(req, res);  
     }
   ```

At time of login pass email as username and passport will match it with email stored in db.

Comment: i am not using jwt here.

Comment: In that case, simply comment that code and pass user in json